# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function error when creating dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I am trying to create an onlick event that opens a dialog box but I keep getting a Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function error.

HTML

```
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <input type="button" value="Button " id="add" />
                </div>
                <div id="dialog" hidden="hidden">
                    Hiiii
                </div>
```

JQUERY

```
            $(function() {
              $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false
              });

              $("#add").click(function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog('open');
              });
            });
```

Debugger points to

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
```

as being the source of the error

Comment: Have you included jQuery-UI? And after jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Add your jquery code before end of the body tag.

```
   <script>
      $(function() {
                  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false
                  });

                  $("#add").click(function() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog('open');
                  });
                });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: As long as it's after the jquery and jquery-ui includes and you're using `$()` onload, it doesn't need to be at the end of the body.